# what kind of database should I use for EMR system?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net, web

I would like to create an EMR system. Any suggestion on what kind of database should I use and how to implement such? By the way im planning on using ASP.NET for the website. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on many things the database selection. Some of them are, what knowlegde you have in which database, the amount you may storage, if you want to pay(??? i think you don't :)). And other thing. Is a big conversation. You have to provide more details.

Comment: Im planning on using SQL. But since I only have basic knowledge about SQL, and Im task to do the database of an EMR (which is also new to me) that we are about to develop, Im having hard time on how will I start.

Comment: You mean Microsoft SQL i suppose. Again you will need an estimation of data you be imported in order to select ms sql express or not.

Comment: let us say that i need a flexible one. The one that I can adjust on an expanding database

Comment: flexible is a big word. For some people Oracle is flexible, or DB2 or what ever.

Comment: Ok i'll try to research for more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked for a medical company earlier and for EMR they used Sql Server but for HL7 it was Hadoop.

You can use any RDBMS, but it really depends on many factors.

Comment: have you ever develop an EMR system?  If yes any tips on how will I start? We are 3 working on it. We divide the work as a database admin, a layout artist, and a programmer.

Comment: I can not make any comment as I have no idea at all what depth you need, what are the requirements, you should divide the project flow as per the Agile Software Development model, as it aims to keep development goals and timelines short and sweet.

Comment: Also, first understand the requirements and then you should design the database , if you need any help let me know, i will happy to help.